# How to use value defined in CASE WHEN later in THEN or ELSE block?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's have this query:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT 1+1) > 2 
         THEN (SELECT 1+1) || ' is greater than 2'
         ELSE (SELECT 1+1) || ' is not greater than 2'
       END
```

I would like to assign `(SELECT 1+1)` to variable in `CASE WHEN` block and then use in `THEN` or `ELSE`.
`(SELECT 1+1)` is of course example. Instead in this place I'm executing a real subquery to db.
Is this possible in plain sql?

Comment: Maybe you need a [`WITH`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)?

Comment: It depends what the content contains. Is that returning a scalar or set?

Comment: @CetinBasoz It returns scalar

Comment: Then it would be possible and likely you would use with a with or lateral as @tadman suggested. You might even create a function depending on your real needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite the query using **WITH** as below

```
WITH tempTable(val) as (SELECT 1+1) 
     SELECT 
        CASE WHEN val > 2  THEN val || ' is greater than 2' 
        ELSE val || ' is not greater than 2' END FROM tempTable
```

As suggested by *@tadman*, the documentation for WITH can be found [here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)